# Nuget pack always using Release folder

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package for a specific build configuration. Let's use Debug as an example. I run the command:

nuget pack path_to_my.nuspec -Properties "Configuration=Debug;"-Verbosity Detailed

It throws me the following error:

Attempting to build package from 'path_to_my.nuspec'.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found: 'bin\Release\mydll.dll'.

As you can see, it tries to get the dll from bin\Release, and not bin\Debug.

Is it possible to tell nuget to use a different Configuration than Release, or use another path?

Comment: Are you using Windows Powershell?  Do you have Co-App tools installed?  I ask because I do and when I do a `which nuget` that nuget executable is older which causes me trouble.  What version are you running?

Comment: @matap very interested to know more details of this problem and find a fix that would work for you. Could you please file a bug at https://github.com/nuget/home/issues and provide all the relevant details (nuget.exe version, the exact command line you are using) along with a repro project if possible? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your nuspec?

Answer (score 2):

It would be necessary to check your nuspec file just in case you have hardcoded the Release path to `bin\Release\mydll.dll`, which is seems it's the case.

A valid nuspec file would have references to the dll without specifying the environment. Use wildcard to allow for any environment. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProject</id>
    <authors>iberodev</authors>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <projectUrl>https://www.diegodrivendesign.com/</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Sample</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\*\netstandard2.0/ProjectOne.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin\*\netstandard2.0/ProjectOne.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin\*\netstandard2.0/ProjectTwo.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin\*\netstandard2.0/ProjectTwo.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

then you run the `nuget pack` command to reference your nuspec. Make sure you have compiled the code for the proper environment so that the dll that the nuspec references are available (e.g: `dotnet build --configuration Debug`)

```
nuget pack ./*NuGet/*.nuspec -Version 1.0.0 -OutputDirectory foo -Prop Configuration=Debug -Verbosity detailed
```